# localhost http 500 internal server error

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

Sometimes, the localhost that i am using gave me that "http 500 error" whenever i try to access it. But, restarting the computer solved that problem and I could access my files, until today. Today, even though i have changed nothing with my codes(same as yesterday), I cannot access my localhost and phpmyadmin even if i restart the pc.
How can i solve it? what went wrong? I dont think that the problem is about my code structure because if it was I could not access localhost yesterday(I changed nothing)

Comment: What does the web server error log say?

Answer (score 7):

Check the error log, it should have a more detailed description of the error. If you're using Apache look for a file named `error.log` probably in a folder called `log`

Comment: I found apache_error file which gives. Child 3528: Starting 150 worker threads.
Child 3528: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
Child 3528: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
Terminating on signal SIGTERM(15). Is it what i am looking for

Comment: Possibly .. it doesn't look like an error though, just a kill command. Is there anything else in the file?

Comment: It works again. I dont know how. Do you think it is because of a virus?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I am also Have the same issue with the localhost so I eneble the rewrite mode of my wamp server and solve this issue.

For Localhost :

Apache -> Apache Modules -> rewrite module

Enable it and restart the services.